# Grouping nested document

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch querying and probably this question is not so smart, but I would appreciate any help. Is there any idea how I can query only events in the following sample json user session (field "l"):

```
{
  "dvs_t": 103492673,
  "l": [
    {
      "e": "SessionInfo",
      "p": {
        "Device": "samsung GT-P6800",
        "SessionNumber": "36"
      },
      "ts": 103279627
    },
    {
      "e": "InAppPurchaseCompleted",
      "p": {
        "ItemID": "sdbundle_stars_10",
        "TimePlayed_Total": "3 - 3.25 Hours"
      },
      "ts": 103318595
    }
  ],
  "osv": "4.1.2",
  "request": "ANME",
  "srv_ver": "0.2"
}
```

For instance, can I somehow

- count the number of `InAppPurchaseCompleted` events in the session?
- count the number of `InAppPurchaseCompleted` events in the sessions grouped by session parameter `request` or any other parameter?

Comment: Hope my answer helped, feel free to ask any questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Filter in Elasticsearch allow you to search (really quickly) on a specific set of data. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html.

If you only want to return count you can use search type count http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#count